# Does the Torah have a gender?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, hebrew, grammatical-gender

Within the talmud, is the Torah as an entity referred to with with a particular gender and if so are there exceptions?

Comment: I think it's normally feminine.

Comment: are you talking about the word "torah" (which is feminine) or about the words for the symbols of the torah (like a "tree of life") in which the word "tree" is masculine, though I'm sure others are feminine or about something else?

Comment: Hebrew does not have a *neutral* pronoun like the English word *it*. Is this the question that you are asking?

Answer (score 7):

The noun has to be gendered, as Semitic languages like the Talmuds' Aramaic and Hebrew have no neuter nouns.

"Torah" is a feminine noun. But "Sefer" (book -- whether bound pages or a scroll) is a masculine one. So that "Sefer Torah", is a masculine idiom, since the noun is "sefer" and "Torah" just modifying it.

Which leads to this interesting contrast between verses.

Devarim 28:61:

> גַּ֤ם כׇּל־חֳלִי֙ וְכׇל־מַכָּ֔ה אֲשֶׁר֙ לֹ֣א כָת֔וּב בְּסֵ֖פֶר הַתּוֹרָ֣ה הַזֹּ֑את יַעְלֵ֤ם יְהֹוָה֙ עָלֶ֔יךָ עַ֖ד הִשָּׁמְדָֽךְ׃

> Also every sickness and every plague which is not written in this (הזאת, feminine) Seifer Torah, Hashem will raised against you until you are destroyed.

Devarim 29:20:

> וְהִבְדִּיל֤וֹ ה֙' לְרָעָ֔ה מִכֹּ֖ל שִׁבְטֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל כְּכֹל֙ אָל֣וֹת הַבְּרִ֔ית הַכְּתוּבָ֕ה בְּסֵ֥פֶר הַתּוֹרָ֖ה הַזֶּֽה׃

> Hashem will single them out from all the tribes of Israel for misfortune, in accordance with all the sanctions of the covenant recorded in this (הזה, masculine) book of Torah.

[Rashi on the latter verse](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.29.20?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=bi) notes the difference in gender, and explains that the difference is in the *trop*. In the first case, there is a *tipecha* on the word "בְּסֵ֖פֶר - *basefer* / in the book" (look under the ס), distancing it a bit from the word "*Torah*". This "this" is the Torah, so it is "*zos*", in the feminine. In the second case, the בְּסֵ֥פֶר הַתּוֹרָ֖ה are joined -- *basefer* getting a *mercha* and only "*Torah*" getting the *tipecha*. The "this" is "*Sefer Torah*", not just "*Torah*".

I don't know any exception to the above in the Talmuds. (Although I don't think the text that we have of the Talmud Yerushalmi is stable or original enough that we could analyze a detail like the gender used in a quote.)

Answer (score 2):

The word "Torah" is a feminine noun in Hebrew, indeed it follows the classic feminine Hebrew pattern of ending in the letter "ה ". As proof, please see the linked article which cites a popular phrase "v'zot HaTorah" ("and this is the Torah") using *zot*, the feminine form for the word for *this* rather than ze, the masculine form: https://torah.org/torah-portion/mikra-5771-vaeschanan/